# Power Virtual Agent authentication settings cannot be edited in a managed solution

Tags: bots, power-platform, power-virtual-agents

I have a power virtual agent in my power platform dev environment. It uses Azure AD Authentication and works fine in dev. When I export a managed solution and import it into my test environment, the bot returns:

```
Authentication is not configured for this bot Error code: AuthenticationNotConfigured
```

However, if I go to edit the authentication settings for the virtual agent to turn on authentication, I am unable to do so. While it silently fails, if I go to the dev tools and look at the details of the network call, it is a 500 error with the message:

```
{
"ErrorCode": 7509,
"ErrorMessage": "Request REQ_ID XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX AuthTicketId  failed with error InternalServerError (Internal Server Error): {\"error\":{\"code\":\"0x8004f026\",\"message\":\"The evaluation of the current component(name=bot, id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX) in the current operation (Update) failed during managed property evaluation of condition: Managed Property Name: iscustomizableanddeletable; Component Name: bot; Attribute Name: iscustomizable; \"}}",
"ErrorInfo": null,
"Error": {
    "RetryIn": null,
    "InnerErrors": [],
    "Code": "UnexpectedError",
    "Message": "Request REQ_ID XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX AuthTicketId  failed with error InternalServerError (Internal Server Error): {\"error\":{\"code\":\"0x8004f026\",\"message\":\"The evaluation of the current component(name=bot, id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX) in the current operation (Update) failed during managed property evaluation of condition: Managed Property Name: iscustomizableanddeletable; Component Name: bot; Attribute Name: iscustomizable; \"}}",
    "Properties": {},
    "Diagnostics": null
}
}
```

This makes sense to me as it is a managed solution, so it should not be editable. However, when I look at my exported solution, in the bot.xml file, there is no authentication details. Instead, there's a reference to :

```
<bot schemaname="MYBOT">
    <authenticationconfiguration>{"connectionName":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}</authenticationconfiguration>
```

I have searched through my entire solution for this connection name, but I don't see it defined anywhere. Not in Azure AD, not in the solution, and not in the exported solution zip file.

Is it possible to have a power virtual agent using authentication in a managed solution?